# object as key to map becomes const in cpp

Tags: c++, c++11

can someone please explain why the following code compilation fails with message "passing ‘const apple’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘int apple::foo()’ discards qualifiers", and how to resolve it.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

/*
 * 
 */
class apple{
private:
    int a,b,c,d;
public:
    int foo(){
        return a+b+c+d;
    }
};
class ball{
private:
    map<apple,string> mp;
public:
    void foo2(){
        for(map<apple,string>::iterator it = mp.begin();it!=mp.end();++it){
            cout<<it->first.foo()<<endl;
        }
    }

}
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int foo {...}` -> `int foo const {...}`

Comment: You can't modify the *key* of a map element in place.

Comment: This is not your real code due to a missing `;` that terminates your class declaration. [Here are the errors from the code you posted](https://www.ideone.com/PYjCYU)

Comment: The map relies on key values to order itself. It can't let you modify them in place, to maintain its own invariants.

Comment: StoryTeller's right.  You should make it `int foo() const` so you can call it despite the `apple` being `const` - which will work for you because `foo()` doesn't try to change any of the member data in the `apple`: it should have been `const` in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

Works for me: (added const at the end of foo() and ; on end of ball class). Class apple is a Key in std::map which is declared as const: typedef pair value_type; so accessing key should be also declared as const.

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class apple{
 private:
    int a,b,c,d;
public:
    int foo() const {
        return a+b+c+d;
}
};

class ball{
  private:
  map<apple,string> mp;
public:
    void foo2(){
        for(map<apple,string>::iterator it =   mp.begin();it!=mp.end();++it){
         cout<<it->first.foo()<<endl;
    }
}

};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    return 0;
}
```